# Does python automatically close SSH and Telnet

Tags: python, ssh, telnet, paramiko

This might be bad practice so forgive me, but when python ends on non telnet lib exception or a non paramiko (SSH) exception, will the SSH or Telnet connection automatically close? Also, will sys.exit() close all connections that the script is using?

Comment: I think you should try to close all your connection inside finally block, please have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159644/does-paramiko-close-ssh-connection-on-a-non-paramiko-exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the system (Linux and Windows) keeps track of all of the resources your process uses. It can be files, mutexes, sockets, anything else. When process dies, all of the resources are freed. It doesn't really matter which programming language do you use and how you terminate your application.

There are several subtle exceptions for this rule like WAIT_CLOSE state for server sockets or resources held by zombie processes, but in general you can assume that whenever your process is terminated, all of the resources are freed.

**UPD**. As it was mentioned in comments, OS cannot guarantee that the resources were freed properly. In network connections case it means that there are no guarantee that the FIN packet was sent, so although everything was cleaned up on your machine, the remote endpoint can still wait for data from you. Theoretically, it can wait infinitely long. So it is always better practice to use "finally" statement to notify the other endpoint about closing connection.

Comment: Why does this answer have been downvote ? It's a nice overview of Linux resource management

Comment: The OS can keep track of its own OS-level resources, but it doesn't automatically know how to dispose of arbitrary resources, like things your connection might have started up on a remote machine.

Comment: Yes, actually it is a good point. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

In an interpreter :

```
>>> c = paramiko.SSHClient()
>>> c.connect(hostname="127.0.0.1", username="funkysayu", password="xxxx")
```

So here, let's run a `netstat -putelan | grep ":22"` :

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:47380         127.0.0.1:22            ESTABLISHED 1001       149999     7934/python2        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:22            127.0.0.1:47380         ESTABLISHED 0          150000     -
```

Now let's kill the Python, and run netstat just after (`kill -9 7934 && netstat -putelan | grep ":22"`)

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:47382         127.0.0.1:22            TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
```

It does not close properly the socket (the server is in TIME_WAIT), but the connexion does not exist anymore client-side.

The @Heller's answer explain why it is working like that.